# Сохранения данных в экземпляре класса

Tags: javascript, классы

На странице есть две `<p>` с именем и работой. И есть форма, в которой можно записать новые имя и работу и сохранить на странице. Нужно создать класс, у которого есть два метода. Первый, чтобы обновлять данные внутри класса, второй, чтобы отображать эти данные на стр.

```
class {
  constructor(userName, userJob, inputName, inputAboutMe) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userJob = userJob;
    this.inputName = inputName;
    this.inputAboutMe = inputAboutMe;
  }

  setUserInfo = () => {
    this.inputName.value = this.inputName.textContent;
    this.inputAboutMe.value = this.inputAboutMe.textContent;
  };

  updateUserInfo = () => {
    this.userName.textContent = this.inputName.value;
    this.userJob.textContent = this.inputAboutMe.value;
  };
}
```

где `userName` и `userJob` элементы `<p>`, а `inputName` и `inputAboutMe` инпуты. У меня сейчас просто перекидываются данные из `textContent` в инпуты и наоборот.

После создания экземпляра класса, я хочу сохранить данные внутри экземпляра, вызвав метод `setUserInfo` и отправить их на сервер для хранения, например. Потом поменять данные на странице методом `updateUserInfo` и опять вызвать `setUserInfo`, чтобы обновить данные внутри экземпляра.

Вопрос заключается как раз в том, что значит сохранить данные внутри экземпляра. Если бы это не был класс, я бы инициализировал 2 переменные и занес бы туда данные. Потом бы переписал. А как это делается в классах?

Comment: Думаю почему-то в сторону "приватных" свойств класса. В кавычках, так как настоящей приватности в JS не знаю. Дальше всякие там геттеры и сеттеры для считывания и установки этих свойств. Только жить это всё будет до первой перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: речь идет о сохранении данных в полях класса, у тебя это почти есть, просто ты хранишь не только значения, но и сами html элементы

Comment: @Grundy не понимаю...

Comment: у тебя сейчас 4 поля в классе, в которых хранятся html элементы, нужно добавить еще два, в которых будут храниться строки

Comment: @Grundy получается необязательно при создании экземпляра весь конструктор заполянть? я могу также заполнить 4 поля, а другие два заполню методом?

Comment: не обязательно, можно вообще в конструкторе ничего не заполнять

Comment: @Grundy я безмерно Вам благодарен!